# Getting the error ,' SyntaxError: can't assign to function call '

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

I'm trying to subtract the value in 'remove' variable from either A, B or C without using if...else inside while loop, but it's throwing a syntax error for line 9. What is the reason behind this?

```
print "\t\t\t\t\t  Welcome to the game of piles"
A=3
B=3
C=3
print "A: %d\t B: %d\t C: %d" %(A,B,C)
while A>0 and B>0 and C>0:
    choose_pile = raw_input("\nChoose a pile: ")
    remove = input("How many to remove from pile %s" %choose_pile)
    int(choose_pile)=int(choose_pile)-remove
```

Answer (score 0):

Change int(choose_pile) to choose_pile.

```
choose_pile = int(choose_pile)-remove
```

The variable `choose_pile` will be an int object. If you need to typecast it then you'll have to do that in a different statement such as:

```
x = int(x)
```